# NodeJS npm - Using Contextify on windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm able to build contextify 0.1.1 using node-gyp on Windows, but I don't know how to get npm to recognize/use this version when resolving other modules' dependencies.  'npm install' fails with the same (expected) 'node-waf was unexpected at this time.' error, despite having a build version of contextify in the local directory.

Put simply: how do I tell npm to use a module I've built myself, instead of trying to download/build its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` installs modules into the current directory's `node_modules` directory. So instead of using `npm install` at all, just move/copy the contextify module that you built yourself to `node_modules/contextify`. Unfortunately you will have to do this for any module that depends on `contextify`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this does work.  I was hoping that I could configure npm to treat requests for a certain package differently, i.e. by routing them to some precompiled Windows contextify I had.  Sad that it doesn't work, but still happy to be building on Windows at all.  So thanks!